# MVC Partial View Model Binding with Complex Type Name Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, model-binding

I have a main model and view that shows an employee to edit and a partial model and view that is just a department select list. The strange problem I cannot figure out is that the model binding does not work when I have the DepartmentVm property name as `Department`, but works when it is `Departments`. When i changed the property name from `Departments` to `Department`, i made sure I updated the HtmlFieldPrefix to `Department` too and I checked the name for the select list in the HTML, which was `Department.DepartmentName`. Am i missing something? Thank you.

```
public EditUserVm()
{
    Roles = new UserRoleVm();
    Department = new DepartmentVm();
}

[Display(Name = "Windows ID")]
[Required]
public string WindowsIdName { get; set; }
[Display(Name="Employee Name")]
public string UserFullName { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Email { get; set; }
[Required]
public UserRoleVm Roles { get; set; }
[Required]
public DepartmentVm Department { get; set; }

public class DepartmentVm
{
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public SelectList DepartmentSelectList { get; set; }
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "create-user-form" }))
{

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.Partial("_Department", Model.Department, new ViewDataDictionary()
            {
                TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Department" }
            })
  ....continued code
```

Comment: Consider using a Editor Template instead of a view, it should make it infinitely easy to make the model binder happy.

Comment: yea i thought about that because I have a few templates in my application, but I think this problem was more of an annoyance because I could not figure it out. I appreciate the help.

Comment: even with the editor template it is binding to the plural name of my property only. I wonder if something is up with my model binder? I have other similar setups and they work fine.